# Extetions Tab Not on GNOME Tweak

Tags: gnome, themes

I am trying to install themes to my system so I can have the look I want. Everywhere I looked seems to point to GNOME Tweak, and so far the app has worked fine. However, the Shell option is locked due to it saying I haven't enabled the User Theme extension. I have tried installing the theme, as well as all of the extensions I have been told, however the Extensions tab still seems to not exist. How would I fix this so I can enable the User Theme option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are now using 22.04 LTS with GNOME v40 matters have changed.

You should search for `Extension Manager` (use left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key) and when open you should see an extension listed called `User Themes`. 
Select <kbd>Install</kbd>

[image]